# Is the service hourly pricing based on allocation or consumption?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Where with allocation I mean, that for how much time have I "assumed the ownership" of the resource.

And with consumption I mean, how much has the resource actually been used for.

For example, single vCPU:

- My app engine works for a whole month, 24/7 = `30 * 24` = `720h`.
- Average CPU usage is `60%` for the whole month.
- Do I pay fixed price for `720h`, or...
- Do I pay calculated price for `720h * actual usage (60%)` = `432h`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Billing is based on clock time, not percentage used during that time period.

If your usage of a compute resource is 0%, you will still pay for it (assuming that the compute resource is running and not shutdown).

Comment: You know of any other cloud provider that bills based on actual usage?

Comment: No I don't. I work with the major vendors (AWS, Azure, Google, IBM, Alibaba). Their pricing is based on clock time. Since your use case does not consume one App Engine resource entirely, I am not covering autoscaling, load balancing, etc where you can get economy of scale for larger compute infrastructures.  Keep in mind that most of your billing will be storage costs and bandwidth. These items are usually larger than compute charges. For the cloud vendors the money is not so much in compute resources but storage and bandwidth charges.

Answer (score 1):

[Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#standard_instance_pricing) and [flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#flexible-environment-instances) environment pricing differ from each other by the granularity of billing:

- a few instance classes in standard env vs a wider range of combinations of vCPU and memory units
- some (small) differences in terms of uptime calculation and start/stop offsets

But fundamentally both charged based on consumption (as in uptime, not in effective CPU used!).

Scaling matters as well:

- automatic and basic scaling shut down idle dynamic instances, more or less bringing the answer close to "consumption" for them.
- manual scaling as well as resident instances in automatic/basic scaling are charged as "allocation" as they'll be always running